# Using a CDN with RequireJS optimiser

Tags: requirejs

RequireJS allows one to load libraries from a CDN. In case the CDN is down, one can also have a backup option where the file can be located some where else (in this case, we assume it is located locally). This is all done in the paths object. For example, in order to load JQuery from a CDN and then locally if the CDN is down, do this:

```
    paths : {
    jquery : [ 
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
        'lib/jquery',
    ]}
```

The above example would first try find query from the CDN, then from lib/jquery.

**Question**
I am under the impression that when using the requirejs optimiser, things get minified and obfuscated into one large file. How would the a backup option work in the optimiser? Would it be included in the minified file? If so, then there is absolutely no advantage to using a CDN. But if the backup option is not included in the optimised version, then how will optimised code cope if the CDN goes down?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have different configuration settings for your regular site vs. what you use to feed the optimizer, so in this case you would use an "empty" config in your optimizer version so that it doesn't include jQuery in the combined/minified version:

```
paths: {
    jquery: "empty:"
}
```

See the documentation for further details:
http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

Comment: Yeah, I know about this, but then what is the use of that "backup option". I mean, this code is going to be used in production far more than in test. It seems to me that the Backup option is utterly useless because who uses unoptimized JavaScript.

Comment: If by unoptimized you mean not combined with other modules, then yes you have a good point. But there's nothing which says your backup file can't be minified. Also, you would expect that when using a CDN it will be loaded successfully a high percentage of the time.

Comment: Thanks, you have answered my question in this last comment. By unoptimised, I do mean not combined. I have no idea why this option even exists. It would be very cool if this backup option would be loaded asynchronously if the CDN failed, but that may be difficult to achieve with AMD. James Burke, if you are reading this (what are the chances!), please can you think about this.